# how can I get warn message instead of error message using requiredMessage attribute?

Tags: primefaces

I want to get warn message using requiredMessage attribute.
can I get?
if possible,
how can I solve my problem?

without changing managed bean Can I achieve it?
means without using FacesMessage can I ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy (and safer) way would be to do the check on server side. 
Check for the field, and if its null or empty you can create a FacesMessage.

```
String message = "Your message here";
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,message,null);
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
facesContext.addMessage(null,facesMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you handle it programatically:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, header, message));
```